# Upgrading rails / reloadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, reloadable

I have tried to upgrade my rails in order to deploy a old RoR app into Heroku,
Unfortunately I'm getting some errors and I have no clue how to fix this. It seems that  `include Reloadable` from my model isn't working anymore:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Artist::Reloadable (NameError)
    from /disk1/home/slugs/123146_6bfd10b_0628/mnt/app/models/artist.rb:2
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
     ... 23 levels...
```

My previous install was using RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '1.1.2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloaded has been deprecated for a long time.  Check this out: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/8/11/reloading-revamped

The functionality you're looking for may now be automatically built into rails.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deleting the `include Reloadable`